# Store user credentials in a local file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, data-binding, desktop-application

I am developing an app in C# .NET. The app will not connect to any database and during the installation it will create files and settings for the application and user. I want to store user data in a local file such as text file or flat file or JSON file.

In simple words I want to prevent user opening the file but if somehow user find a way to open it then at least he should not understand what information is stored. Is there any good method to encrypt file and data in it?

Just like how Google chrome stores data:
1  ŒA  û  œA  àû  ¯A  `ü  ÂA  °ü  ÒA   ý  åA  Pý  õA  À% B  & B  p& (B  °m <B   n OB  ðn bB  Po uB  °o ˆB`  q ›B  Àq ®B   r ÁB  €r ÔB  s çB  pt úB  °u
C  @v  C   v 3C   x FC  Àx YC   z lC  P| C  °| ’C  ð} ¥C  P~ ¸C  0 ËC   ÞC   € ñC  `€ D    D   ‚ *D  °ƒ =D  „ ND`  „

Comment: you can  encrypt the password before stored, for more security you can use 1 way encryption with salt so if one found the hashed password then cannot get the original password. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try encrypting the file and decrypt it when you need to access it.

[Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-6.0)
[Decryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.decrypt?view=net-6.0)

Example of encryption and decryption from MS Docs:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace FileSystemExample
{
    class FileExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string FileName = "test.xml";

                Console.WriteLine("Encrypt " + FileName);

                // Encrypt the file.
                AddEncryption(FileName);

                Console.WriteLine("Decrypt " + FileName);

                // Decrypt the file.
                RemoveEncryption(FileName);

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Encrypt a file.
        public static void AddEncryption(string FileName)
        {

            File.Encrypt(FileName);
        }

        // Decrypt a file.
        public static void RemoveEncryption(string FileName)
        {
            File.Decrypt(FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some example code and/or deeper explanation to your answer. Links might die.

Comment: Your link says that this shouldn't be used in .net core apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-6.0#remarks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple text encryptor that you can use. Simply encrypt the text before storing it and decrypt it as you need it.

This will not stop someone who is willing to spend a little bit of time with a debugger, but just like locking your door it will keep honest people honest.

I also included some unit tests, feel free to remove them.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Encryption;
public static class SimpleEncryptor
{
    public static async Task<string> EncryptAsync(string cleartext, string password)
    {
        var hasher = SHA256.Create();
        var key = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var iv = aes.IV;

        var byteStream = new MemoryStream(10000);
        byteStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
            byteStream,
            aes.CreateEncryptor(),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        
        var encryptWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        await encryptWriter.WriteAsync(cleartext);
        encryptWriter.Close();        

        var bytes = byteStream.ToArray();
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        return base64;
    }
    public static async Task<string> DecryptAsync(string ciphertext, string password)
    {
        var hasher = SHA256.Create();
        var key = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        var encryptedArray = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
        var byteStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedArray);

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
        var numBytesToRead = aes.IV.Length;
        var numBytesRead = 0;
        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            var n = byteStream.Read(iv, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            if (n == 0) break;

            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        }

        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
               byteStream,
               aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
               CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        
        var decryptReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
        var decryptedMessage = await decryptReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        
        return decryptedMessage;
    }
}


public class EncryptorTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("How do you turn this on?", "Swordfish", "GHzrU6z5hsgb6HSJtMZyirEs11sHY/X4l5zElwxHz9jpIGA+D9TAxv7SEU31/Jgb")]
    [TestCase("Orange you glad I didn't say banana?", "hunter12", "qqNFxhwKYkkYzsN0vDzWhQguZ7f9xc+60duZXQATAzQslRhJsn6lc691+yVR0SWJYDJUD9ZbezpW/v4vYi6qeA==")]
    [TestCase("Orange you glad I didn't say banana?", "hunter12", "TsjCbMOT4UKVi6L43Kkc0rMsl6IyeEfLBR3ruAsG+APUjb1zesVLGA/B0yF4FkFV/j1Rc5B55ClZYHV2zoubBA==")]
    [TestCase("Your mother is rather fat.", "12345", "WD8e5E+PtQ5kMqkPSIZa18pDutbqn8OroSU5utHFTuikbgIWLA4IRAHihrfiXrV6")]
    [TestCase("Yer' a wizard harry!", "Swordfish", "Z6tF/3iDTu72qTeVnKa8DZOsL5NFD9XfqJTWebANVrjQysm+8ps3Z9RuoJyenk30")]
    public async Task TestDecryption(string text, string password, string ciphertext)
    {
        var decoded = await SimpleEncryptor.DecryptAsync(ciphertext, password);

        Assert.AreEqual(text, decoded);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("How do you turn this on?", "Swordfish")]
    [TestCase("Orange you glad I didn't say banana?", "hunter12")]
    [TestCase("Your mother is rather fat.", "12345")]
    [TestCase("Yer' a wizard harry!", "Swordfish")]
    public async Task TestEncryptAndDecrypt(string text, string password)
    {
        var ciphertext = await SimpleEncryptor.EncryptAsync(text, password);

        var decodedtext = await SimpleEncryptor.DecryptAsync(ciphertext, password);

        Assert.AreEqual(text, decodedtext);
    }
}
```